# Retaining value of shared preference if application is killed by system

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In Android, will the values in shared preference be retained if the application is killed because of low memory in the device?

Comment: If preference is applied, yea, it will persist. But no if it is not.

Answer (score 2):

To Retaining  value of SharedPreferences you have to commit or apply the value.

```
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putString(ID_ONE, “Value_1”);
                    editor.putString(ID_TWO, “Value_2”);
                    editor.putString(ID_THREE, “Value_3”);
                    editor.apply();
```

`“editor.apply();”` is recommended .

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is the purpose of using shared preferences . The storage is persistant

**From Official documentation**

> If you don't need to store a lot of data and it doesn't require structure, you should use SharedPreferences. The SharedPreferences APIs allow you to read and write persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings.
>
> The key-value pairs are written to XML files that persist across user sessions, even if your app is killed

[link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage)

Answer (score 0):

Yes It does.If you don't like to kill the app or would like to exclude from background under recent apps you can add this code under application tag on AndroidManifest.xml

```
        `android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"`
```

But add shared preference value to retain the app preference so that the screen state would be same the next time you open the app.